# Probability question about poker. Doubt about the order of events.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

Poker dice is played by simultaneously rolling 5
dice. In how many ways can I have a) a pair; b) a double pair?

To the first question I did: 
$\binom52\cdot\binom61\cdot\binom51\cdot\binom41\cdot\binom31=3600$ ways.

Of 5 dices, I select 2 to form a pair, and to this pair, i'll select 1 number from 6; After this, I'll have 3 dices left, and 5 numbers left to pick. So, to each dice I'll select 5*4*3 numbers, respectively.

To the second question I did:
$\binom52\cdot\binom32\cdot\binom61\cdot\binom51\cdot\binom41=3600$ ways

From 5 dices, I pick 2, and then from 3 left, I pick 2. Then, for one pair I'll pick one number from 6, and to the other pair I'll pick one from 5 numbers. Lastly, i'll pick 1 from 4 numbers to the single dice.

Why did I get it wrong if I'm doing the same technique? I'm distributing one number to 1 pair of dices, or to each dice. Shouldn't it get right since I'm doing the exact same thing on both cases?

Thanks

Comment: I think you're counting things twice in the second question. Let's denote the five dices A, B, C, D and E. One of your choice is to first choose A and B to form the first pair and then choose C and D for the second one. But another of your choices is to choose C and D first and then A and B. You will count the same hand twice.

Comment: @NeedForHelp what part of the answer you say it's wrong?

Comment: In your answer to the second question, I believe $\binom{5}{2}\cdot\binom{3}{2}$ should be $\frac{1}{2}\cdot\binom{5}{2}\cdot\binom{3}{2}$ to account for the fact that you count each hand twice.

Comment: @VitorAguiar You can also use $ \binom62 $ instead of $ \binom61 \cdot \binom51 $. Thus, you select a pair of numbers, and then assign the smaller of them to the first selected pair of dices and the largest to the second one.

Comment: @needforhelp if I want a pair, why can't I do binom `52 * binom 31 * binom 21* binom 11 * binom 64` ??  Why I am ordering the dices, and I just select 4 numbers to this "groups"

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting values and positions, so order matters, but only once.   You can select the values (unorderly) then positions (orderly), or you can select positions (unordered) then values (orderly).

So you might select two values, then places into which you put the highest value, places into which you put the lowest, and a value for the lone into the remaining place.

$$\binom 62~\binom 5 2\binom 32~\binom 4 1$$

Or you might select four places and divide them into two pairs (indistinguishable), then select values for the leftmost and rightmost pair, and a value for the remaining lone .

$$\binom 54\binom 42\frac 1{2!}~\binom 61\binom 51~\binom 41$$

Same thing.

Where as in the first answer you correctly selected places for the pair and a value for it, then values for each of the remaining three lones.   You could also have selected three values for the lones then places for each value.

$$\binom 61\binom 52\binom 51\binom 41\binom 31=\binom 61\binom 52\cdot\binom 53\binom 31\binom 21\binom 11$$

Comment: I agree that the order doesn't matter. But, by doing binom 5 2 * binom 3 2 am I counting with order? Well, I suppose yes, because the five dices belong to the same group, so I am switching places

Comment: But when you say "\binom 31\binom 21\binom 11" aren't you switching the places of dices? So you're doing something that we don't want, which is counting the order

Comment: Sorry.  To be clear:  You are selecting values and positions, so order matters, but only once.  You can select a values (unordered) then positions (orderly), or you can select positions (unordered) then values (orderly).$$\binom 53\text{ values into }\binom 31\binom 21\binom 11\text{ position for the highest, middle, and lowest value} \\ = \binom 33\text{ positions and } \binom{5}{1}\binom 41\binom 31\text{ values into the leftmost, middle, and rightmost positions}$$

Comment: ok, I understood what you've said, it really helps me how to think. But now it brings me a lot of other doubts also. 1) (Select a par) So, lets say I will pick the numbers unordered, and i'll pick the dices orderly:

`$$\binom 52\binom 31\binom 21\binom 11\binom 64`
On a group of 5 dices, I am choosing 2 to be a par, and another 3, and since I am multiplying each other and they belong to the same group, the order does matter. And then, from 6 numbers, I select 4 distinct numbers. It makes sense to me... :\

Comment: 2) (double par) `$$\binom 52\binom 32\binom 11\binom 11\binom 63` I select 2 dices from 5 to be a pair, 3 from 2 to be a pair, I'm ordering them. And then I select 3 numbers from 6, unordered, to the 2 pairs and to the single. It makes sense to me. 


3) (three alike) `$$\binom 53\binom 32\binom 63` I select 2 numbers from 6, one to be a a three of a kind, and the others two to the single dices

Comment: you there? I hope you help me.

Answer (score 1):

Your first one is right.

Other easy ones are no pair, which is $6\cdot 5\cdot 4 \cdot 3\cdot 2=720$,
triplets which is $\binom{5}{2}\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot 4 =1200$, quads which is 
$5\cdot 6\cdot 5 = 150$, full house which is $\binom{5}{2}\cdot 6\cdot 5=300$ and of course five a a kind, which is just $6$.

Your second is wrong because you double counted hands with pairs on $(A=B),(C=D)$ along with $(C=D),(A=B)$ -- those are the same ways of picking which dice form the two pairs, but you are counting them separately.  One way to look at it is that you pick one die to *not* be paired (five ways) then pick how the remaining four dice are paired up -- **three** ways, not six.  Then you assign a number to the pair involving the leftmost paired dice, a number to the other pair , and a number to the loner.  This gives $5\cdot 3\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot4 = 1800$.

You can then add the ways to get $6^5=7776$, as must be the case.

Comment: You got it correct. But lets take the case of full house, per example: I order the position of dices, or I order the position of numbers. But lets say I want to order  the dices. Why is this incorrect? 

`$$\binom 52\binom 32\binom 62`

If I got a bag of 5 numbers, and If I do binom 52 * binom 32 I am ordering  one pair with another, like you said. So, if I do the same thing to 1 pair and 1 triplet why is this incorrect?

Comment: For the full house, once you decide which three are the triplets, the other two slots are determined, so that part is just $\binom{5}{3}$ (or $\binom{5}{2}$) without the $\binom{3}{2}$ you want to multiply in.

Comment: yes, I got it. What about if I had 6 dices, and I wanted 3 pairs. Would it be $$\binom 62\binom 42\binom 22\ binom 63\$$ ?
And what about if I wanted 2 pairs and 2 different singlets?